# Why I cant properly change the size of the input width in percentage using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with making my input field good looking and not too big.
The problem is that when I add to input the w-25 class thats width 25% the input width changes according to its original width and not the parent container and it leaves blank space inside the  container , I can fix the problem by passing the width in pixels but I am supposed to use only bootstrap and no css styling.Maybe there could be a different approach to making it.

```
    <div class="container my-5">
      <h1 class="fw-normal">Fibonacci Calculator</h1>
      <div id="calculatorContainer" class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <span>The Fibonacci Of</span>
        <small>
          <input
            type="number"
            class="mx-2 d-inline-block w-25"
            placeholder="#"
          />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ls</button>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a codepen with the front end
https://codepen.io/amirovalex-the-animator/pen/OJjgbpo

Comment: If you remove the parent element, which is <small> the w-25 seems to be more successful. Do you need the small?

Answer (score 0):

You can use col-md-1 col-12 on the input class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).